# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery when used with swift?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I am using javascript in swift. I am using JavaScriptCore for this. I have created a serrated JS file & loading it. Below is code for JS file.

```
function setOldCities(appCities) {        
  var city_array = appCities.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < city_array.length; i++) {
    // Trim the excess whitespace.
    city_array[i] = city_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");

    jQuery('.map-pin').each(function() {
      if (($(this).attr('city') == city_array[i])) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        try {
          webkit.messageHandlers.callFromActivity.postMessage();
        } catch(err) {
          console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I am calling this function from swift class. Function is getting called but it does not recognise what is jQuery.

Code to call function from swift.

```
func callJsFunction() 
{
  if let functionFullname = self.jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("setOldCities") {
    // Call the function that composes the fullname.
    filter = "City1,City2";
    if let fullname = functionFullname.call(withArguments: [filter]) {
      print("JS RESULT \(fullname)")
    }
  }
}
```

From below Code I am loading JS file into swift context.

```
func initializeJS() {
        self.jsContext = JSContext()

        // Add an exception handler.
        self.jsContext.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
            if let exc = exception {
                print("JS Exception:", exc.toString())
            }
        }

        // Specify the path to the jssource.js file.
        if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "maps", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "map/js") {
            do {
                // Load its contents to a String variable.
                let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)

                // Add the Javascript code that currently exists in the jsSourceContents to the Javascript Runtime through the jsContext object.
                self.jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
            }
            catch {
                print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        let consoleLogObject = unsafeBitCast(self.consoleLog, to: AnyObject.self)
        self.jsContext.setObject(consoleLogObject, forKeyedSubscript: "consoleLog" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol))
        _ = self.jsContext.evaluateScript("consoleLog")
    }
```

**map-pin** class is in separated html file. I have included **maps.js** in html file

Comment: I can't tell from the code above -- have you imported jQuery anywhere?

Comment: I imported in index.html

Comment: Could you complete the code with jQuery for a code snippet??

Comment: I added all code

Comment: Can anyone help me with this problem

Comment: Dhiraj - did you ever find a solution for this? I have a similar problem.